# Removing PolyLine from googlemaps v2

Tags: java, android, eclipse, google-maps

I am trying to remove a polyline from `GoogleMaps V2`

On Marker Drag, i want to change the polyline drawn from previous marker to the dragged marker,

Here is the class for marker drag, but in it how can i remove the polyline?

```
 mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() 
        {

            public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) 
            {
            }

            public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) 
            {
mMap.addPolyLine(///)
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139271/google-maps-android-api-v2-how-to-remove-polylines-from-the-map/67250574#67250574

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can call `clear()` to remove all markers, polylines, and polygons from your `GoogleMap`. Or, you can call `remove()` on the `Marker`, `Polyline`, or `Polygon` to remove an individual element from your map.

Comment: what if i add them in an array like Polyline poly = mMap.addPolyline() and then at later poly.remove();

Comment: @MuhammadUmar: Ah, my apologies. I had expected to see `remove...()` methods on `GoogleMap` and did not realize that they were individual methods on the instances themselves. I have updated my answer to reflect this fix. Having your `Polyline` objects in a collection is fine, though you will need to somehow determine which `Polyline` is the one that you need to `remove()`.

Comment: @CommonsWare I have tried as you said `polygon.remove();` but map still contains polygon. :(

Comment: @CommonsWare, your answer was really helpful, but I edited it in order to explain how to get the objects in the first place. I hope it was helpful too :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove a single `Polyline` from the map, you will have to add it in a slightly different way:

```
List<Polyline> lines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();

lines.add(googleMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
        .addAll(lineCoordinates)
        .width(width)
        .color(color))); //the line will appear on the map here

lines.get(0).remove(); // the line should disappear
```