# Google Maps Android API v2, how to remove Polylines from the map?

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2

I am trying to remove previously added Polyline and redraw new Polyline when the location has been changed. I tried both

**this.routeToDestination.setPoints(pointsToDestination) and 
    this.routeToDestination.remove()**

but neither of them worked.

I followed [How to draw a dynamic line (route) with Google Maps Android API v2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13933411/how-to-draw-a-dynamic-line-route-with-google-maps-android-api-v2) but could not resolved the issue

```
    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        routeToDestination = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
                .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                        new LatLng(this.destinationLatitude, this.destinationLongitude))
                .width(1)
                .color(Color.DKGRAY)

        );
    }

   @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {

        List<LatLng> pointsToDestination = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        pointsToDestination.add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()));
        pointsToDestination.add(new LatLng(destinationLatitude, destinationLongitude));

        this.routeToDestination.setPoints(pointsToDestination);
    }

}
```

Comment: `remove()` is supposed to work, according to the documentation. Make sure that you are on the latest version of the "Google Play services" library in the Extras area of your SDK Manager (latest right now is "rev 5") and that you are using that library project. If the problem persists, create a sample project demonstrating the error post it, perhaps as an issue to the Maps issue tracker: http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/list

Comment: thanks, I'm gonna try

Comment: do I have to apply changes to the map separately (calling a function) ?

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: updating the "Google Play services" library resolved the issue, thank you

Answer (score 47, accepted):

To remove a polyline you should simply use remove() method as stated in the API.

```
//Add line to map
Polyline line = mMap.addPolyline(new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude()),
                    new LatLng(this.destinationLatitude, this.destinationLongitude))
            .width(1)
            .color(Color.DKGRAY)

//Remove the same line from map
line.remove();
```

Comment: I am having similar difficulties. I call setPoints on a polyline and there are still artifacts that never get removed from the previous points. It seems to be a timing thing as the faster I update points the worse is the effect.

Answer (score 1):

The Simplest way to do that

```
implementation 'com.akexorcist:google-direction-library:1.2.1'
```

Use this library Get an API key from

```
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions/get-api-key
```

You must enable the billing method for this for direction API.

```
https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector2/billing/enable
```

Set this code in any function but not in the onmapready function

```html
 String serverKey = "YOUR_API_KEY";
      GoogleDirection.


        GoogleDirection.withServerKey(serverKey)
                .from(new LatLng(30.677717,73.106812))
                .to(new LatLng(31.345394,73.429810))
                .transitMode(TransportMode.WALKING)
                .unit(Unit.METRIC)
                .execute(new DirectionCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDirectionSuccess(@Nullable Direction direction) {


                        Log.d("eeeeee", direction.getStatus());

                        if(direction.isOK()) {
                            // Do something
                            Route route = direction.getRouteList().get(0);
                            Leg leg = route.getLegList().get(0);

                            ArrayList<LatLng> directionPositionList = leg.getDirectionPoint();
                            Log.d("eeeeee", directionPositionList.size()+"eeeeee");
                            if (polylineOptions_final!=null)
                            {
                                polylineOptions_final.remove();
                            }
                            PolylineOptions polylineOptions = DirectionConverter.createPolyline(getApplication(), directionPositionList, 10, Color.RED);
                            polylineOptions_final = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
                        } else {
                            // Do something
                        }
//                        Log.d("eeeeee"+direction.getGeocodedWaypointList().toString(), "onDirectionSuccess: ");


                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onDirectionFailure(@NonNull Throwable t) {
                        Toast.makeText(ClientMap.this, "d"+t.getMessage().toLowerCase(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    }
                });
```

new LatLng(31.345394,73.429810));

Answer (score 0):

Make a Member variable in map activity of polyline

```
    Polyline polyline_final = null;
```

Every time when a polyline is added to map than assign value of map like this

```
polyline_final = mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);
```

And next to make new polyline at same time remove the previous polyline form map Apply this if condition before
polyline_final =  mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions);

```
if (polylineOptions_final!=null)
                        {
                            polylineOptions_final.remove();
                        }
```

Now this is done