# issue with removing polyline google map v2 android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-maps-v2

I am adding a polyline option simply as in google developer's website.

```
PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
        .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
        .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)); // Closes the polyline.

// Get back the mutable Polyline
Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

I want to remove it. but there is no `rectOptions.remove()` 
I did update google play services from my sdk as mentioned in [Google Maps Android API v2, how to remove Polylines from the map?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15139271/google-maps-android-api-v2-how-to-remove-polylines-from-the-map)
But still I dont have it. Should I do something more after just updating it from SDK manager? I really need to remove it and not make it invisible to save memory cause I will show a path of lots of points and for many times.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To remove the `Polyline`, use `polyline.remove();`

Comment: So I guess when you declare with PolylineOptions x; you cannot use remove(). remove is only defined for Polyline objects.. So I used this one

Comment: PolylineOptions only helps to make the initialisation of the polyline easier (the same for the other *Options classes). You need to do every manipulation of the polyline on the polyline itself.

Comment: @Mokus I have polygon, and i am doing same thing as you post answer but that will not remove map from Map, How can i refresh it ? [See doc](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polygon#remove%28%29)

Comment: also need `map.clear();`. but should be careful about other things on map! :)

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't use `PolylineOptions` to remove it.

Use `PolyLine` like this

```
polyline.remove();
```

***[Documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Polyline?hl=en)***

```
public void remove ()
```

*`Removes this polyline from the map. After a polyline has been removed, the behavior of all its methods is undefined.`*

Comment: Yes I got it. I changed to Polyline. Thanks Mitesh