# Remove a line from PolyLine map in Google Map android V2?

Tags: android, google-maps, google-polyline

I have searched in google and find this **[answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15155822/issue-with-removing-polyline-google-map-v2-android)** where i can remove all polyLine of a Map. 
But I want to remove only a particular line from the poly Line. For Example I want to remove the line from 2nd to 3rd LatLng in the given code. I want to change color of a particular line of a  polyLine or make it transparent. And I  also want to add a `clickListener` to **PolyLine**

```
   PolylineOptions rectOptions = new PolylineOptions()
            .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0))
            .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.0))  // North of the previous point, but at the same longitude
            .add(new LatLng(37.45, -122.2))  // Same latitude, and 30km to the west
            .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.2))  // Same longitude, and 16km to the south
            .add(new LatLng(37.35, -122.0)).width(5).color(Color.RED);; // Closes the polyline.

Polyline polyline = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions);
```

Main goal is to `remove/make it transparent` a particular line of a PolyLine on click or tap.

```
PolylineOptions line= new PolylineOptions().add(HAMBURG,// these are latlong
                                                            KIEL,
                                                            KIEL2,
                                                            KIEL3
                                                        new LatLng(40.748963847316034,
                                                                   -73.96807193756104)
                                                            )
                                                   .width(5).color(Color.RED);



                    Polyline polyline=  googleMap.addPolyline(line);
```

And i want to remov line between KIEL1 and KIEL2

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to manually remove points from the polyline.

EDIT:

Step by step:

Create a List of polylines:

```
List<Polyline> mPolylines = new ArrayList<Polyline>();
```

Add PolylineOptions to the map:

```
Polyline polyline1 = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions1);
Polyline polyline2 = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions2);
Polyline polyline3 = myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions3);
```

Then save the added polylines to your array

```
mPolylines.add(polyline1);
mPolylines.add(polyline2);
mPolylines.add(polyline3);
```

Now at any time you can trim the polyline like so:

```
// Get polyline1
List<LatLng> points = mPolylines.get(0).getPoints();
// Set the bounds of points to remove (inclusive)
int startPoint = 1, endPoint = 2; // will remove kiel1 and kiel2
// Remove the points
for (int i=startPoint; i<=endPoint; i++) {
    points.remove(i);
}
// Added this line as getPoints returns a copy
mPolylines.get(0).setPoints(points);
```

Now in theory this should work fine. I found that the points don't actually change after setPoints.

I even tried:

```
Polyline polyline = mPolylines.get(0);
// Get copy of the points
List<LatLng> points = polyline.getPoints();
mPolylines.get(0).remove();
mPolylines.remove(0);
for (int i=3000; i<7000; i++) {
    points.remove(i);
}
// Create a PolylineOptions object with the new points
PolylineOptions polylineOptions = new  PolylineOptions().addAll(points);
mPolylines.add(0, mMap.addPolyline(polylineOptions));
```

And to my surprise a new Polyline was added (I can tell by the changed stroke width and color), but it still used the old points, even though `points.size()` returned the correct (trimmed) count.

I'm not sure why this is so, perhaps some error in my code. You can try these methods yourself and see if you are any luckier.

Comment: i have update my question . Kindly tell me how i remove line between KIEL1 and KIEL2

Comment: @Nepster updated my loop, to make more sense (made it inclusive). It will remove kiel1 and kiel2 points.

Comment: mPolyline.add(myMap.addPolyline(rectOptions));  statement is not working . giving errors

Comment: @Nepster Ahh that's a typo. It supposed to be `mPolylines.add` not `mPolyline.add`. Updated.

Comment: Nothing happens because you have remove LatLng from points List whereas you are assigning rectOptions instead of List<LatLng> points. i must have to add points but they are not adding because it is a list<latLng>

Comment: @Nepster updated with step by step solution. Please be more specific with your problems if you still face any.

Comment: I understand what to do but not know how to do? I will explain it to you. you have created a list<LatLng> after removing points from it. Now i have to create a new PolyLine using these points and remove the previous one and set the latest one. Only tell me how can i create

Comment: +1 for your help . Now i understand what to do i will accept your answer after I have finished my work and completed your answer.

Comment: @Nepster I finally understood what you ment and tried it myself. Indeed the polyline isn't changing and i'm getting very weird behaviour here. Nevertheless see my updated answer and try it yourself.